# Does this limit property of a function have a name?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, functions, continuity

For a function $f : M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ on some metric space $(M,d)$, suppose that for each $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that

$$
\forall\, x,x_0\in M \ : \ \quad |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \varepsilon \ \quad \ \Longrightarrow \ \quad d(x,x_0) < \delta.
$$

Does this property of $f$ have its own name?

Comment: Is this the intended implication? Otherwise, this would just be [uniform continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity#Definition_for_functions_on_metric_spaces) if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @mrtaurho. The implication is intended as stated, so it's not uniform continuity.

Comment: I think this means that $f$ is injective and that the inverse function of f is uniformly continuous (check!).